# Toggle active nav-link

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a problem with toggling the active nav-link using JavaScript. I think my CSS is causing some problems but I do not know why.

I have the CSS code down at the bottom if that is any help. I have linked Jquery and my own `name.js` document correctly in my HTML head. I want to toggle the active link when it is visited.

```js
var header = document.getElementById("nav-bar")
var toggled_nav = document.getElementsByClassName("nav-item")

for (var i = 0; i < toggled_nav.length; i++) {
  toggled_nav[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    var current = document.getElementsByClassName("active");
    current[0].className = current[0].className.replace(" active", "");
    this.className += " active";
  });
}
```

```css
#nav-bar {
  margin: 27px auto 0;
  position: relative;
  width: 610px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #34495e;
  border-radius: 8px;
  font-size: 0;
}

#nav-bar a {
  line-height: 50px;
  height: 100%;
  font-size: 15px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#nav-bar .animation {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 0;
  transition: all .5s ease 0s;
  border-radius: 8px;
}

a:nth-child(1) {
  width: 100px;
}

a:nth-child(2) {
  width: 110px;
}

a:nth-child(3) {
  width: 180px;
}

a:nth-child(4) {
  width: 110px;
}

a:nth-child(5) {
  width: 110px;
}

nav .start-home,
a:nth-child(1):hover~.animation {
  width: 100px;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #1abc9c;
}

nav .start-about,
a:nth-child(2):hover~.animation {
  width: 110px;
  left: 100px;
  background-color: #fcf75e;
}

nav .start-blog,
a:nth-child(3):hover~.animation {
  width: 180px;
  left: 210px;
  background-color: #3498db;
}

nav .start-portefolio,
a:nth-child(4):hover~.animation {
  width: 90px;
  left: 400px;
  background-color: #9b59b6;
}

nav .start-contact,
a:nth-child(5):hover~.animation {
  width: 110px;
  left: 500px;
  background-color: #e67e22;
}
```

```html
<nav id="nav-bar">
  <a class="nav-item" href="#">HOME</a>
  <a class="nav-item" href="#">POKEMON</a>
  <a class="nav-item" href="#">LEAUGE OF LEGENDS</a>
  <a class="nav-item" href="#">API-DOC</a>
  <a class="nav-item" href="#">ABOUT US</a>
  <div class="animation start-home"></div>
</nav>
```

Comment: What is the style for active class? How do you distinguish a bare `.nav-item` and a `.nav-item.active`?

Comment: The colors for the different navbar-items but i want that color to stay on when the specific navbar-items is toggled.

Answer (score 0):

I simplified your code and created specific active classes for each nav. You can give the parent the click handler and refer to the children through `e.target` since in this case the children take up the full space of the parent.

```js
var header = document.getElementById("nav-bar")

header.addEventListener("click",function(e){
   has_class = header.querySelector(".active");
   if(has_class)has_class.classList.remove("active");
   e.target.classList.add("active");
});
```

```css
#nav-bar {
    margin: 27px auto 0;
    position: relative;
    width: 610px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #34495e;
    border-radius: 8px;
    font-size: 0;
}

#nav-bar a {
    line-height: 50px;
    height: 100%;
    font-size: 15px;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    cursor: pointer;
}
#nav-bar .animation {
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 0;
    transition: all .5s ease 0s;
    border-radius: 8px;
}

.active{
border-radius: 8px;
}

a:nth-child(1) {
    width: 100px;
}
a:nth-child(2) {
    width: 110px;
}
a:nth-child(3) {
    width: 180px;
}
a:nth-child(4) {
    width: 110px;
}
a:nth-child(5) {
    width: 110px;
}

a:nth-child(1).active{
    background:#1abc9c;
}

nav .start-home, a:nth-child(1):hover~.animation {
    width: 100px;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #1abc9c;
}

a:nth-child(2).active{
    background:#fcf75e;
}

nav .start-about, a:nth-child(2):hover~.animation {
    width: 110px;
    left: 100px;
    background-color: #fcf75e;
}

a:nth-child(3).active{
    background:#3498db;
}

nav .start-blog, a:nth-child(3):hover~.animation {
    width: 180px;
    left: 210px;
    background-color: #3498db;
}

a:nth-child(4).active{
    background:#9b59b6;
}

nav .start-portefolio, a:nth-child(4):hover~.animation {
    width: 90px;
    left: 400px;
    background-color: #9b59b6;
}

a:nth-child(5).active{
    background:#e67e22;
}

nav .start-contact, a:nth-child(5):hover~.animation {
    width: 110px;
    left: 500px;
    background-color: #e67e22;
}
```

```html
<nav id="nav-bar">
            <a class="nav-item" href="#">HOME</a>
            <a class="nav-item" href="#">POKEMON</a>
            <a class="nav-item" href="#">LEAUGE OF LEGENDS</a>
            <a class="nav-item" href="#">API-DOC</a>
            <a class="nav-item" href="#">ABOUT US</a>
            <div class="animation start-home"></div>
        </nav>
```

Comment: One problem, how the animation stops and stays when the link is active?

Answer (score 0):

For the first two `.nav-item` I see they are referring to different files. So in their curresponding files, you can mark them `active`.

For rest of the three `.nav-item` you can use (I am using JQuery since you mentioned it)

```js
$('#nav-bar').on('click', '.nav-item', function(e) {
    $('.nav-item.active', e.currentTarget).removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
}
```

make sure the css for the `.active` is being applied correctly.

Comment: it works very well, except i do not know how the colors tag along when the specific link is active.

Comment: What do you mean? Can you create a snippet?

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this; where you remove the active class for each item and then add it to the one that was clicked.

```
let items = document.querySelectorAll(".nav-item")
items.forEach(item => {
  item.addEventListener("click", event => {
    const current = document.querySelector('.active')
    current.classList.remove('active')
    item.classList.add("active")
  })
})
```